# How to generate iOS build from Flutter so my client can test the app in their iPhone device?

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, flutter-ios

I want to generate an iOS build from Flutter to test in a multiple physical iPhone devices. I'm using macOS. with latest xcode installed, flutter-sdk, dart sdk and Development editor tool using Android Studio. any one has experience with this process. your precious help is strongly needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow these directions there very clear.  https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos

Make sure you've set everything up to build/compile in a mixed environment.

Next do: In Xcode, open Runner.xcworkspace in your app’s ios folder.
To view your app’s settings, select the Runner project in the Xcode project navigator. Then, in the main view sidebar, select the Runner target.
Select the General tab.

Details found here:  https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios